# Multiline equation in a table

Tags: latex

Is there a way to make very long equation multiline so it doesn't stretch the table very long?

Comment: I agree with Johannes. What is your problem? What is the desired result? Do you want smaller equation text? Or do you want to put less stuff on each line and have the equation span more lines? One of two things has to happen for an equation to fit in a box... either the box has to be big enough, or the equation has to be small enough! :-).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `p{<length>}` type column to wrap the cell contents into a paragraph. Or used `aligned`, etc., from amsmath to create a boxed multiline math expression.

Answer (score -1):

You can break the equation with the `split` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    x &= a + b \\
    \quad + c + d \\
    &= x \cdot y \cdot z
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```